# How do I remove one tablix that's stuck inside another

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I was moving tablixes around my page and ended up with some stuck inside the header row of another like so;

[image]
 It definitely isn't overlaid, I have that going on with my other tablixes at the top of the page, as intended. These have somehow merged so when I try to grab the corner handle I have to click it multiple times to turn into the move handle and then only the main table is moveable, I can't grab and move the tables that have merged into the bigger one.

It's stopped the report from running and I can't find a way to take it out, I can't undo past a certain point either as I saved and rebooted my PC before I realised it was this problem that was causing my errors.

Does anyone know any way to take the damn things back out or do I have to redo hours of work? :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the screenshot below.

1. Click somewhere inside the nested table.  You should see the column/row outlines like in the picture

[image]

1. Left click the top left corner handle[image]
2. Ctrl-x to cut and then ctrl-v to paste somewhere else on the page.

Answer (score 1):

In a broader context, you can use the right-click and then Select option to select any item that is layered with others.

[image]

Comment: Very good point.  Especially useful for picking a specific piece of a chart.